# Suspended mode in the UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

I have the UWP application that uses ReactiveUI for viewmodel to view binding. When the user gets logged in to the app the (when the log in command is executed) the following method is called:

```
private void RegisterActivityTrackingFunctionality()
    {
        Container = _container;
        Container.Resolve<IDialogService>().IsActive = true;
        _dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        _timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Subscribe(_ => CheckActivityTime());
    }
```

The timer is created to monitor users activity in the application. If the user is inactive for more than 15 minutes he is logged off from the application. Basically method CheckActivityTime() is called for this purpose:

```
private void CheckActivityTime()
    {
        _logger.Info("In a CheckActivityTime Method");
        if (Container.Resolve<TokenHolder>().IsActivityTimeElapsed)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Dispose();
            }

            Task.Run(async () => await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Container.Resolve<IDialogService>().IsActive = false;

                    var dialogService = Container.Resolve<IContentDialogService>();

                    if (dialogService.CurrentContentDialog != null)
                    {
                        dialogService.CurrentContentDialog.Hide();
                    }

                    var shellViewModel = Container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>();

                    if (shellViewModel.Router.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
                    {
                        shellViewModel.Router.NavigateBack.Execute(null);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error("The unhandled exception occured in UI thread for logout mechanism", ex);
                }
            }
            ));
        }
    }
```

The problem is like that: When app goes to suspended mode it does not always logout the user if the inactivity time exceeds 15 minutes. 
Could anyone explain to me, what is the problem?
Maybe there is something wrong with timer setting? Or maybe I should not do the logout operation on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is attach a handler to `OnResuming` event of App which is called each time app is resumed from suspended state and then check for the `Activitytime` and lock your app from there.

```
Application.Current.Resuming += new EventHandler<Object>(App_Resuming);
```

Comment: The problem is that timer works properly, but sometimes the logout does not occur even if the inactivity time was exceeded. I was not able to reproduce this problem locally, cause locally it works properly. All the cases of improper application work were received from production.